# Multiple paragraphs in a multirow cell?

Tags: tables, paragraphs, multirow

I'm trying to write multiple paragraphs inside a multirow cell,... but I can't find how! I've tried a lot of options, but none of them worked.
First of all, I'll show you what I would like to get:

[image: Whised Table]

And using the next file, I get the next table:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{hhline}
    \usepackage[left=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|b{6cm}|m{0.3cm}|m{10.2cm}|}
    \hline
    A & B & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox{10.2cm}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer sit amet tincidunt ante, suscipit consectetur urna. Maecenas cursus libero turpis, fermentum aliquet metus malesuada et. Pellentesque auctor tellus nibh, et dignissim urna dictum ut. Nam posuere nulla odio, posuere convallis massa facilisis sit amet.}
    \parbox{10.2cm}{Proin sed nisl tellus. Ut dapibus imperdiet dignissim. Integer rhoncus fringilla ipsum, non fringilla ipsum imperdiet non. Curabitur nisl felis, imperdiet a vestibulum vel, consectetur hendrerit tortor. Etiam metus nisi, hendrerit eget metus at, luctus posuere massa. Sed non lorem lobortis odio eleifend ultrices quis sed arcu. Aenean quam lectus, ornare ut risus ac, rutrum mattis.}} \\ \cline{1-2}
    C & D & \\ \cline{1-2}
    E & F & \\ \hline
    G & H & I \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

    \end{document}
```

[image: Obtained Table]

I have to say that I've tried with

```
    \p
    \par
```

And all options with those... but I'm stacked!

Anyone who can direct me to the right solution?

Thanks.

Comment: For the records, this works out if the box as of multirow v. 2.7 (2021/01/29).

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to use a blank line to denote a paragraph break but unfortunately `\multirow` currently doesn't allow `\par` (looks like an easily fixable bug) but here as almost always you can use `\endgraf` as an alternative command without the restrictions of `\par`.

[image]

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{hhline}
    \usepackage[left=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}
%multirow manual page 14
   \newcommand{\mystrut}{\rule[-40pt]{0pt}{100pt}}


    \begin{tabular}{|b{6cm}|m{0.3cm}|m{10.2cm}|}
      \hline
      A\mystrut & B & \multirow{3}{=}{\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
              adipiscing elit. Integer sit amet tincidunt ante,
              suscipit consectetur urna. Maecenas cursus libero
              turpis, fermentum aliquet metus malesuada
              et. Pellentesque auctor tellus nibh, et dignissim urna
              dictum ut. Nam posuere nulla odio, posuere convallis
              massa facilisis sit amet.
\endgraf
    Proin sed nisl tellus. Ut dapibus imperdiet dignissim. Integer
              rhoncus fringilla ipsum, non fringilla ipsum imperdiet
              non. Curabitur nisl felis, imperdiet a vestibulum vel,
              consectetur hendrerit tortor. Etiam metus nisi,
              hendrerit eget metus at, luctus posuere massa. Sed non
              lorem lobortis odio eleifend ultrices quis sed
              arcu. Aenean quam lectus, ornare ut risus ac, rutrum
              mattis}
 \\ \cline{1-2}
    C\mystrut & D & \\ \cline{1-2}
    E\mystrut & F & \\ \hline
    G & H & I \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: I had similar question which doesn't involve multiple paragraphs. Interestingly, I made a mistake when trying to reproduce your example and accidentally realized that my problem seems to be solved with a construction of the type `\multirow{}{}{}\endgraf` or `\multirow{}{}{}\par`. But I can't find a straightforward explanation as to why! Here's [an example](http://ideone.com/iwGinS) (which I'm hosting on ideone.com due to comment restrictions) and here's [how it renders for me](http://i.imgur.com/QeLQ2xr.png).

Comment: (Although the vertical separation between rows one and two is not optimal...)

Answer (score 2):

Same preamble as the OP. The trick is to adjust `\\[xcm]` the parameter x and use p{} for column specification.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|b{6cm}|p{0.3cm}|p{10.2cm}|}    \hline
A & B & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{10.2cm}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer sit amet tincidunt ante, suscipit consectetur urna. Maecenas cursus libero turpis, fermentum aliquet metus malesuada et. Pellentesque auctor tellus nibh, et dignissim urna dictum ut. Nam posuere nulla odio, posuere convallis massa facilisis sit amet.}}\\ [2cm]
& &\multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t][5cm]{10.2cm}{\vspace{0.5cm} Proin sed nisl tellus. Ut dapibus imperdiet dignissim. Integer rhoncus fringilla ipsum, non fringilla ipsum imperdiet non. Curabitur nisl felis, imperdiet a vestibulum vel, consectetur hendrerit tortor. Etiam metus nisi, hendrerit eget metus at, luctus posuere massa. Sed non lorem lobortis odio eleifend ultrices quis sed arcu. Aenean quam lectus, ornare ut risus ac, rutrum mattis.}} \\  \cline{1-2}
C & D & \\ [2cm] \cline{1-2}
E & F & \\  [2cm] \hline
G & H & I \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OK, this one works fine (Thanks a lot, @Jesse) and the other one too (Thanks @Gilean0709), but... it's tricky, because you are using 12 false rows... I mean: Isn't there any _"legal"_ way to do it? Using just the rows and columns that are printed? Or is it just an imposible thing what I am asking?

Comment: Hi, you are welcome. The solution I proposed has the same number of rows as your OP. Sorry, not quite follow you.

Comment: Ups! Sorry, I placed the answer in the wrong place.

Comment: Your solution has 5 rows (instead of 4 _real_ rows). You are using two multiple rows instead of one multiple row. Is it possible your solution using only one multiple row?

Comment: @user37244 -- When I saw your OP a few days back, I observed the second parbox was over the boundary and that gave me a hint that \\ was not issued because this is a tabular and you need that to go to the next row. Moreover, without & &, the second parbox will start from column 1 (the leftmost column), resulting in 5 rows. Although there are many ways to solve your problem, I tackled it by following the logic behind a tabular.

Answer (score 1):

This is perhaps not the most elegant solution, but it works. For the second paragraph I added a \\[\baselineskip]. You have to adjust the height of the rows manually. I think that is a general problem with multirow and at least I don't know a better solution for it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|b{6cm}|m{0.3cm}|m{10.2cm}|}
\hline
A & B & \multirow{3}{10.2cm}{\parbox[t]{10.2cm}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer sit amet tincidunt ante, suscipit consectetur urna. 
Maecenas cursus libero turpis, fermentum aliquet metus malesuada et. Pellentesque auctor tellus nibh, et dignissim urna dictum ut. 
Nam posuere nulla odio, posuere convallis massa facilisis sit amet.\\[\baselineskip] 
Proin sed nisl tellus. Ut dapibus imperdiet dignissim. Integer rhoncus fringilla ipsum, non fringilla ipsum imperdiet non. Curabitur nisl felis, 
imperdiet a vestibulum vel, consectetur hendrerit tortor. Etiam metus nisi, hendrerit eget metus at, luctus posuere massa. Sed non lorem lobortis 
odio eleifend ultrices quis sed arcu. Aenean quam lectus, ornare ut risus ac, rutrum mattis.}} \\[4\baselineskip]
\cline{1-2}
C & D & \\[4\baselineskip] 
\cline{1-2}
E & F & \\[4\baselineskip] 
\hline
G & H & I \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gilean0709, but you are using 12 false rows... I mean: Isn't there any "legal" way to do it? Using just the rows and columns that are printed? Or is it just an imposible thing what I am asking?

Comment: @user37244 I edited my answer and combined my previous answer with Jesse's answer. Instead of the false rows I just added some space after each row. Now you don't have to change the number of rows and columns.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does work. But would someone happen to know if anything has changed in those three years? I find it strange that the `multirow` package forces you to manually specify row heights.